# How can I include empty lists in query syntax linq?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I am wanting to find the cartesian product from several lists:

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3};
var list2 = new List<string> { "A" };
var list3 = new List<int>();
```

The end result I am trying to get is a list of objects with every possible combination:

```
{ list1Value: 1, list2Value: "A", list3Value: null },
{ list1Value: 2, list2Value: "A", list3Value: null },
{ list1Value: 3, list2Value: "A", list3Value: null }
```

To accomplish this I am using linq query syntax:

```
var combinations = from value1 in list1
    from value2 in list2
    from value3 in list3
    select new Combination
    {
        List1Value: value1,
        List2Value: value2,
        List3Value: value3
    }
```

However, because `list3` is empty, `combinations` also is empty. If I give `list3` at least 1 item then everything works correctly. How can I handle the empty lists in the query syntax so that it still selects from the other lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var list2 = new List<string> { "A" };
var list3 = new List<int>();

var combinations =
    from value1 in list1
    from value2 in list2
    from value3 in
        list3
            .Select(x => (int?)x)
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        List1Value = value1,
        List2Value = value2,
        List3Value = value3
    };
```

The key change is to use `.Select(x => (int?)x)` which turns an `int` into a `int?` that then allows `.DefaultIfEmpty()` to return `null`, thus making the output clear when the value was missing.

The output I get is:

[image: output]

If I make this change:

```
var list3 = new List<int>() { 0, 4 };
```

...then the output becomes:

[image: alternative output]